# Django Annotated Query to Count all entities used in a Reverse Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-orm

This question is a follow up question for this SO question : [Django Annotated Query to Count Only Latest from Reverse Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60570090/4411196)

Given these models:

```py
class Candidate(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Status(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class StatusChange(BaseModel):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey("Candidate", related_name="status_changes")
    status = models.ForeignKey("Status", related_name="status_changes")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Represented by these tables:

```
candidates
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Beth         |
|  2 | Mark         |
|  3 | Mike         |
|  4 | Ryan         |
+----+--------------+

status
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Review       |
|  2 | Accepted     |
|  3 | Rejected     |
+----+--------------+

status_change
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+
| id | candidate_id | status_id | created_at |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 1            | 1         | 03-01-2019 |
|  2 | 1            | 2         | 05-01-2019 |
|  4 | 2            | 1         | 01-01-2019 |
|  5 | 3            | 1         | 01-01-2019 |
|  6 | 4            | 3         | 01-01-2019 |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

I wanted to get a count of each status type, but only include the last status for each candidate:

```
last_status_count
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| status_id | status_name | count  |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| 1         | Review      | 2      | 
| 2         | Accepted    | 1      | 
| 3         | Rejected    | 1      |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

I was able to achieve this with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60577297/4411196):

```py
from django.db.models import Count, F, Max

Status.objects.filter(
    status_changes__in=StatusChange.objects.annotate(
        last=Max('candidate__status_changes__created_at')
    ).filter(
        created_at=F('last')
    )
).annotate(
    nlast=Count('status_changes')
)

>>> [(q.name, q.nlast) for q in qs]
[('Review', 2), ('Accepted', 1), ('Rejected', 1)]
```

The issue however, is if there is a status not reference by any status change, it's omitted from the result. Instead, I would like to count it as zero.
For example, if the status were

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Review       |
|  2 | Accepted     |
|  3 | Rejected     |
|  4 | Banned       |
+----+--------------+
```

I would get:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| status_id | status_name | count  |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| 1         | Review      | 2      | 
| 2         | Accepted    | 1      | 
| 3         | Rejected    | 1      |
| 4         | Banned      | 0      |
+-----------+-------------+--------+

>>> [(q.name, q.nlast) for q in qs]
[('Review', 2), ('Accepted', 1), ('Rejected', 1), ('Accepted 0)]
```

#### What I tried

I solved this by doing an outer join in SQL but I am not sure how to achieve that in Djano.
I tried creating a queryset with all counts annotated as zero and the merging it, but it did not work:

```py
last_status_changes = Status.objects.filter(
    status_changes__in=StatusChange.objects.annotate(
        last=Max('candidate__status_changes__created_at')
    ).filter(
        created_at=F('last')
    )
).annotate(
    nlast=Count('status_changes')
)
zero_query = (
    Status.objects.all()
    .annotate(nlast=Value(0, output_field=IntegerField()))
    .exclude(pk__in=last_status_changes.values("id"))
)

>>> qs = last_status_changes | zero_query
>>> [(q.name, q.nlast) for q in qs]
[('Review', 3), ('Accepted', 1), ('Rejected', 1)]
# this would double count "Review" and include not only last but others
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

### Update 1

I was able to solve this with a Raw Query using a right join, but would be great to do this using the ORM

```
# Untested as I am using different model names in reality
SQL = """SELECT
        Min(status.id) as id
        , COUNT(latest_status_change.candidate_id) as status_count
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            candidate_id,
            Max(created_at) AS latest_date
        FROM
            api_status_change
        GROUP BY candidate_id
        )
    AS latest_status_change
    INNER JOIN api_candidates ON (latest_status_change.candidate_id = api_candidates.id)
    INNER JOIN api_status_change ON 
        (
            latest_status_change.candidate_id = api_candidates.id 
            AND 
            latest_status_change.latest_date = api_status_change.created_at
        )
    RIGHT JOIN api_status AS status  ON (api_status_change.status_id = `status`.id)
    GROUP BY status.name
    ;
"""
qs = Status.objects.raw(SQL)
>>> [(q.name, q.nlast) for q in qs]
[('Review', 2), ('Accepted', 1), ('Rejected', 1), ('Accepted 0)]
```

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the queryset below:

```py
qs_last_status_changes = StatusChanges.objects
    .annotate(
        _last_change=models.Max("candidate__status_changes__create_at")
    ).filter(created_at=models.F("_last_change")

qs_status = Status.objects\
    .annotate(count=models.Sum(
        models.Case(
            models.When(
                status_changes__in=qs_last_status_changes, 
                then=models.Value(1)
            ),
            output_field=models.IntegerField(),
            default=0,
        )
    )
)
```

```
>>> [(k.name, k.count) for k in qs_status]
[('Review', 2), ('Accepted', 1), ('Rejected', 1), ('Accepted 0)]
```

Thank you Andrey Nelubin for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The only one problem here is that you are filtering your `State` queryset by existing status changes and expecting complete opposite results. In your case the solution is to get rid of obsolete filtering

```
last_status_changes = Status.objects.annotate(
    nlast=Count('status_changes')
).order_by(
    '-nlast'
)
```

The other case would be if you want really filter you changes (by date for example)

```
changed_status_ids = Status.objects.filter(
    status_changes__created_at__gte='2020-03-03'
).values_list(
    'id',
    flat=True
)

Status.objects.annotate(
    c=Count('status_changes')
).annotate(
    cnt=Case(
        When(
            id__in=changed_status_ids,
            then=F('c')
        ),
        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
        default=0
    )
).values(
    'cnt',
    'name'
).order_by(
    '-cnt'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to use it as is (was giving me counts but no including lastest only), but it set me in the right direction and I was able to solve it using Case When